# Can Microsoft OneNote for mobile devices save files outside of OneDrive?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, tablet

**Can Microsoft OneNote for mobile devices save files outside of OneDrive?**

Some of our colleagues use OneNote on their tablets (read: iPad and Android), and are suggesting we deploy it company-wise, meaning that every manager in the company would receive a company-owned, company-configured iPad or Android tablet and be officially instructed to take notes with it during meetings. In order to do that, we would need to save files on the company file-servers, because we cannot trust Microsoft with any work-related data. Said file-servers are accessible via shared folders, WebDAV and an internal OwnCloud installation.

The problem is, it looks like mobile OneNote apps for iOS and Android have two limitations:

1. they need to be signed-in to a Microsoft account (the iOS app would not even launch otherwise)
2. they save files exclusively on Microsoft's servers

Is it truly so? Isn't there a *paid* version that removes those restrictions?

Please come forward with any suggestion on how to circumvent this. One solution we already thought of is asking Microsoft, but we think they will want to make us maintain an on-premises sharepoint server, while we would prefer to rely on our battle proven file-server.

Another option would be to embrace one of Microsoft OneNote's competitors, but it would have to meet those requirements:

1. a similar feature set to OneNote's
2. specifically, support for stylus pen handwriting
3. a corresponding desktop app to edit, organize and otherwise work with those notes taken on the field from the comfort of a desktop workstation

We already have OneNote installed on every desktop and notebook company-wise, as part of a Microsoft Office Professional 2010, 2013 or 2016 installation. The desktop version of OneNote *can* save files to a user-specified location on the local file-system. I believe a similar option *should* be the default for all apps on any platform, but it seems Microsoft thinks otherwise.

I'd like to add that managers are pushing towards this because they want to be allowed to officially use a tool they now use unofficially on their personal iOS and Android devices. I think they would resist the introduction of a different device, e.g. a Windows tablet (because they would have to learn its workings) or a different software (unless it closely matches OneNote's interface and functionality).

Comment: The simple answer: Don't use the mobile version of OneNote.  Any Windows 10 tablet has the capability to run the desktop version of OneNote.  Both versions of OneNote have full support for stylus pen handwriting

Comment: "sn't there a paid version that removes those restrictions?" - There is no paid version of OneNote.  Since you do not trust Microsoft with your data, any paid version of Office 365 that would sort of cover what your talking about, isn't an option due to the fact you don't trust Microsoft.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your suggestion, we will look into Windows 10 tablets. It is not an option for us at the moment, for two reasons: Windows 10 has not yet been approved, and the managers would want a device like the ones they are already familiar with because they own them privately.

Comment: @simlev Under the now deleted answer, you asked: " Could you please briefly summarize to me what penalty policy you would trigger?" Each user on Super User can delete his or her own answers but doing it to many times causes the user to be banned from answering! This time, I consulted with a moderator before deleting my answer.

Comment: Alright so; I assumed we were dealing with on-topic hardware.  What you describe doesn't exist for iOS and Android.  You can hypothesize all you want, but if it doesn't exist, it doesn't do you any good

Comment: @Ramhound Please post your "simple answer" as a standalone answer, since it does answer the question even though unfortunately it does not solve our problem in the immediate.

Comment: @Ramhound after a bit of research I found proof of the existence of so-called *hybrid* Office 365 implementations where *probably* files are saved exclusively to an on-premises <horror mode>Sharepoint server</horror mode>. We need to consult with Microsoft and see what they can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't there a paid version that removes those restrictions?

At this time there isn't a paid version of OneNote

> Can Microsoft OneNote for mobile devices save files outside of OneDrive?

Outside of connecting to your Office 365 Business account, no, there isn't at least not on iOS and Android.  Windows 10 machines in the tablet form factor can run the desktop variant of OneNote.  Windows 10 has native support for compatible stylus pens and handwriting